# Adding two lists to the first column and last row of string

Tags: python, arrays, list, class, matrix

I have this code:

```
    def __repr__(self):

    """
    :return: Return a string representation of the board.
    """
    list1=['0','1','2','3','4','5','-']
    list2=['0','1','2','E','4','5']
    output=''
    for row in self.board:

        output=output+str(row)+'\n'


    return output
```

`self.board` is list of lists with the output below,

the output of this is this matrix as string :

```
['_', '_', '_', 'R', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', 'R', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['p', 'p', '_', '_', '_', '_']
```

Now, what I want as you see in the code I have defined two lists , I want to add the `list1` as the first column in this string , and the `list2` as the last row , I still cannot figure out how can I do that exactly..

this is the output I want to do:

```
['0', '_', '_', '_', 'R', '_', '_']
['1', '_', '_', '_', 'R', '_', '_']
['2', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['3', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['4', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['5', 'p', 'p', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['-', '0', '1', '2', 'E', '4', '5']
```

Any ideas to update my code in order to manage that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def __repr__(self):

    """
    :return: Return a string representation of the board.
    """
    list1=['0','1','2','3','4','5','-']
    list2=['0','1','2','E','4','5']
    output=''
    for x in xrange(len(self.board)):
        output = output + str([list1[x]] + self.board[x])+'\n'
    output = output + str([list1[-1] + list2) + '\n'

    return output
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, just need to remove the x before the range xD

Comment: Why range and not xrange?

Comment: Maybe he is in 3.x

Comment: Yeah im in 3.x didn't know its different in other versions sorry

Answer (score 1):

If `board` is exactly as below, then you can add the `list2` to `board`, zip `board`, then zip each row of `board` with a value in `list1`:

```
board = [['_', '_', '_', 'R', '_', '_'],
['_', '_', '_', 'R', '_', '_'],
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
['p', 'p', '_', '_', '_', '_']]
list1=['0','1','2','3','4','5','-']
list2=['0','1','2','E','4','5']
final_board = [[a]+list(c) for a, c in zip(list1, list(zip(board+[list2])))]
new_final_board = [[a, *b] for a, b in final_board]
```

Output:

```
['0', '_', '_', '_', 'R', '_', '_']
['1', '_', '_', '_', 'R', '_', '_']
['2', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['3', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['4', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['5', 'p', 'p', '_', '_', '_', '_']
['-', '0', '1', '2', 'E', '4', '5']
```

Comment: Its like that but I dont want the board size to change thats why im doing it with strings.. I want the size of the board to stay 6x6

Comment: @OdayHajYehia your desired output is 7x7 as well. Can you clarify?

Comment: I know my desired output will be 7x7 but its in strings that mean the main board in my class size wont change only the represenation of it does change.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `enumerate` operation you can get the index and the object in array.

In that way you can print the correct char before you print the line, then print the final line down.

```
def __repr__(self):

    """
    :return: Return a string representation of the board.
    """
    list1 = ['0','1','2','3','4','5']
    list2 = ['-','0','1','2','E','4','5']
    output = ''
    for rowNumber, row in enumerate(self.board):
        output = list1[rowNumber] + output + str(row)+'\n'
    output = output + str(list2)

    return output
```

Comment: But you are adding list to string aint that incorrect , where u did this,
output = output + list2

Comment: Fixed, can you please upvote me @OdayHajYehia ? It's very important to me and I think I did a good job.

Comment: Sure you helped alot aswell I upvoted you great job.